# Go back to previous page if same domain

Tags: javascript, php, https, back-button

I need to create a button to go to the previous page if the last page visited was in the same domain and I have to check what page was. For example if the user come from google, the back button have to redirect to the homepage, if he come from www.domain.com/product the back button have to redirect to that page, if he come from www.domain.com/static the back button have to redirect to the homepage.

I tried with PHP and the $_SERVER HTTP REFERER and if the protocol is http woks fine, but it doesn't work with https, it redirects always to the homepage. It looks like that variable doesn't exists!

How can I solve that problem? JavaScript and history obj can help?

Thanks

Comment: Javascript can't access the URLs in the browser history, this would be a security violation.

Comment: It's a request from the client, it's not to be a jerk. So there is no way to choose where to redirect the user? Why with https doesn't work? Please only constructive answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a session variable to track the current page and check it at the next page, i.e.:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['page_url'])) {
  // visitor has seen another page in this domain
  $previous_page = $_SESSION['page_url'];
}
else {
  // visitor comes from outside, use home page
  $previous_page = 'http://domain.com';
}
// keep the URL of the current page
$_SESSION['current_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```